# Update label value on live is not working

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I`m working on a web application for Blockchain wallet, there I have a method that reads the live current balance of the wallet (from the blockchain). After the reading, I update some labeles that represents the balance (2 different coins type).
The problem is that the update appears only when I refresh the page. Here is the function:

```
            function updateAccountBalance()
            {
                var accountBalanceILS = @await Model.get_ILS_Balance(); //function in the Model
                var accountBalanceETH = @await Model.get_ETH_Balance(); //function in the Model
                document.getElementById("ilsBalance").innerHTML = " ₪" + accountBalanceILS +" | ETH" ;
                document.getElementById("ethBalance").innerHTML = "" +  accountBalanceETH ;
            } //just ignore how I use the innerHTML, believe me its working
```

The problem is because of the @await Model.get_ILS_Balance() and @await Model.get_ETH_Balance(). These functions require 'await'. If not I get null. But because of them, I cannot update the labels without refreshing the page.

I know they are the problem because of this example:

```
            function updateAccountBalance()
            {
                var accountBalanceILS = 1234.2527; //example
                var accountBalanceETH = 151542.2123 //example
                document.getElementById("ilsBalance").innerHTML = " ₪" + accountBalanceILS +" | ETH" ;
                document.getElementById("ethBalance").innerHTML = "" +  accountBalanceETH ;
            } //If I just insert random number, it`s working
```

I would publish the functions get_ILS_Balance and get_ETH_Balance but I`m not sure it necessary. 
How can I overcome this problem and make the update without refreshing the page?
**If you require more information or more code please  just let me know!!**

Answer (score 1):

You need to run them asynchronously as well. I would look into using Promises.

[MDN has a good tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises) on using promises.

Comment: I tried, It didn`t work. I think the problem related to the Model

Answer (score 1):

So far this is what that works for me, but I very hate the solution.

In the client (view):

```
    function updateAccountBalanceAfterBlockchainOperation() 
    {
    var accountBalanceILS=null; 
    var accountBalanceETH = null;
    var echangeRate = @Model.getExchangeRate_ETH_To_ILS(); 
    $.ajax(
    {
     url: "/DappAccount/RecheckBalanceAfterBlockchainOperation",
     type: 'POST',
     async: true,
     data: {},
     success: function (data)
     {
     var accountBalanceETH = data;
     var accountBalanceILS = accountBalanceETH * echangeRate;               
     accountBalanceILS = accountBalanceILS.toFixed(2);
     accountBalanceETH = accountBalanceETH.toFixed(2);
     accountBalanceILS = accountBalanceILS.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
     document.getElementById("ilsBalance").innerHTML = " ₪" + accountBalanceILS +" | ETH" ;
     document.getElementById("ethBalance").innerHTML = "" +  accountBalanceETH ;

     },

     error: function (xhr, text, error) { }    
     });
 }
```

In the server:

(That is not the controller that returned the view, because the method is too general)

```
public async Task<double> RecheckBalanceAfterBlockchainOperation()
    {
        DappAccount account = DappAccountController.myAccount; // myAccount = the model
        double balanceETH = await account.get_ETH_Balance(); //this was suppose to work in the client...
         return balanceETH;
        //await account.get_ETH_Balance() is a method that included in the model,  
        //but the returned value is not update when the call made in the client 
        //no idea why... frustrating...
    }
```